# Why does the code not work in this instance?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am struggling to understand why code wouldn't work. According to the truth table/logic gates for AND and OR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table I would assume that I would be able to have an if statement inside the `for`-loop such that `(p < 2 || p % i == 0)` would work for finding prime numbers but it fails when considering negative numbers.

I know that if you if take out the `p < 2` and write it as an if statement outside this `for`-loop it works, but if the `p < 2` is inside the `for`-loop it does not work. Why is this so?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        int a = 7;
        System.out.println("A is Prime: " + isPrime(a));
        System.out.println();

        int b = 4;
        System.out.println("B is Prime: " + isPrime(b));
        System.out.println();

        int c = -7;
        System.out.println("C is Prime: " + isPrime(c));
        System.out.println();

        int d = 53;
        System.out.println("D is Prime: " + isPrime(d));
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
        for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            if (p < 2 || p % i == 0) {
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: All negative numbers are less than 2. Does that surprise you?

Comment: Why have you tagged `c` when there is absolutely no mention of C in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because for `p < 2`, the **body of the `for` loop is never performed**. Indeed:

```
for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

If `p = 2`, then it initializes `i = 2`, and then checks `i < p` which fails, and hence the body is never executed. It skips the `for` loop, and thus returns `true`.

We can fix it by performing a check before (or after) the `for` loop, and even boost the performance of the loop slighly:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
    if(p <= 2) {
        return p == 2;
    }
    if(p % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= p; i += 2) {
        if (p % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We can simply return `false` first for all values less than `2`, and `true` for 2. Furthermore we only need to iterate up to *√p*, since if there is a value *j* larger than *√p* that divides *p*, then there is a smaller value *i = p/j* that is smaller than *√p* that will already be checked. We furthermore only need to check *odd* numbers, since even numbers are already implied by the division by `2`.

Comment: Thank you very much Willem, that answers my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to invest in [`Math.abs(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
    p = Math.abs(p);
    for (int i = 2; i < p; i++) {
        ...
```

This will ensure that `p` is always non-negative, and your initial assumptions about how the loop should behave are justified.

Comment: But won't this still return `true` for `p=1` and `p=0`?

Comment: @Willem. The original code had `if(p < 2 ...) { return false; }`